# "Files" file manager utility 3.10.1, How do I uninstall it?

Tags: files, filemanager

This thing just showed up one day.  I already have dolphin and Konqueror.  It doesn't show up on the taskbar.  I am running kde, with kdm on Ubuntu Linux 14.04.  Now every time I start my machine, this shows up with the Documents folder open.

I close it down, but every now and then it re-launches itself,  Yet, I can't find any representation of it anywhere, not even in Task Manager (though it could be showing there under a different name).

Answer (score 1):

Some update has changed something involving that program showing "Files" as it's name; The name is very unspecific, and used by multiple different programs. After finding out which programs can be run under this name, the rest of the problem may be easy to solve.

#### Find out which programs show up with the name `"Files"` when run

We need to look into all `*.desktop` files for the name. There, we find the command in the `Exec` line:

`locate -b '.desktop' | xargs grep -ls '^Name.*=Files$' | xargs grep '^Exec.*'`

lists desktop file names and commands for the GUI program `File` - replace that with the exact name you look for - even it it's multiple words (for substring search, leave out the `=` and `$`).

With the command, I find `Files` may be `nautilus`, `dolphin` or `active-filebrowser`:

```
/etc/xdg/autostart/nautilus-autostart.desktop:Exec=nautilus -n
/usr/share/app-install/desktop/nemo:nemo.desktop:Exec=nemo %U
/usr/share/app-install/desktop/plasma-active:kde4__active-filebrowser.desktop:Exec=active-filebrowser -graphicssystem raster %u
/usr/share/applications/nautilus-folder-handler.desktop:Exec=nautilus %U
/usr/share/applications/nautilus.desktop:Exec=nautilus --new-window %U
/usr/share/applications/nautilus.desktop:Exec=nautilus --new-window
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's my solution for Kubuntu 14.04:

```
    sudo apt-get remove furiusisomount nautilus nautilus-data brasero
```

I think `nautilus`, `nautilus-data` and `brasero` where installed when I installed `furiusisomount`.

Comment: He may not want to uninstall more packages, like `brasero`.