# What is the searchable program name of the "Files" application?

Tags: nautilus, filemanager

When in the file manager you click:

**File -> About**

It says "Files" is the name of the program.

When you type "files" in any search, whether on Google or AskUbuntu.com, it isn't very helpful.

What is a person who is having problems with "Files" supposed enter into the search engines?

Comment: Quoting the tag excerpt of [tag:files]: "For questions concerning specifics about the files on Ubuntu. If your question is about the file manager called "Files" in Ubuntu, use the [nautilus] tag instead."

Comment: You can still search for nautilus and get every help you need

Comment: You can't if the File -> About says "Files" instead of "Nautilus"

Comment: The name was given by GNOME, not Ask Ubuntu. GNOME also has "Web", and "Text Editor", IIRC.

Comment: Welcome to Gnome. Where things are the way they are **just 'cuz**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Files" file manager utility 3.10.1, How do I uninstall it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/470830/files-file-manager-utility-3-10-1-how-do-i-uninstall-it)

Comment: Overlapping solution, different problem.

Answer (score 3):

In my case the "answer" was "Nautilus" but that's not really helpful in general because you might have a different file manager under the same name ("Files").  So to be (somewhat) certain here's a more general answer:

When you click on **File -> About**, it doesn't show you the name of the file manager.  It shows you the word "Files".

To find out the name of the program you follow the directions [in this Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/523753/284313):

> #### Find out which programs show up with the name `"Files"` when run
>
> We need to look into all `*.desktop` files for the name. There, we find the command in the `Exec` line:
>
> ```
> locate -b '.desktop' | xargs grep -ls '^Name.*=Files$' | xargs grep '^Exec.*'
> ```
>
> lists desktop file names and commands for the GUI program `Files`

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @littlepootis He asked the question so in his mind his answer is right.

Comment: Maybe you should put the actual name in your answer ;)

Comment: The actual name can be any of a variety of names because the actual application to manage files can be any of the several available under ubuntu.

Comment: You don't have to list the actual names of all of them, but mentioning the name of the one you did find would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try Visiting This Path In

> Files ~> Other Locations (Window Left Corner) ~> Computer

```
/usr/share/applications/
```

If You're Looking For The Files Application In Ubuntu 20+, The Files App Would Be Named As

> org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop

Which Has A File Path

```
/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop
```

Hope You Were Looking The Same

Comment: How can the user know this is the file for "Files", considering there might be over 4000 files in /usr/share/applications?