What it is called similar to explorer or Finder in Ubuntu
What it is called which show files and directory in Ubuntu.
earlier it was called Nautilus but what is the latest 24.04 similar to Finder in MacOS and Explorer in Windows.
and where we can read and understand all these terms for Ubuntu ?

The executable is still nautilus, but the displayed name is "Files"

The converse post from way back when the name change happened: https://askubuntu.com/q/901011/158442
